# Azure Active Directory app service can't connect to Azure Keyvault using user creds/token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to create a web app where a user can explore Azure Keyvault secret information that their azure ad account explicitly has access to. It's an Azure Keyvault dashboard essentially. I'm using Azure Active Directory authentication when the user signs in to the app.  This app is being hosted as an azure app service.

The Azure Active Directory authentication itself is working fine but when I try to connect to Azure Keyvault using the `SecretClient` and `DefaultAzureCredential` from within Azure, it's not working.

Here is the code I'm using to gather secret information:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(this.azureKeyVaultSettings.Value.KeyVaultBaseUrl),
                                      new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
                                                                 {
                                                                     ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = false
                                                                 }));
                                                                     
var secrets = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();

await foreach (SecretProperties secret in secrets)
{
    ...
}
```

Below is the code I have in `Startup.cs`. I feel like the part I'm missing is the storing of the token I'm getting back after signin via oidc and leveraging that in the `SecretClient` somehow. I at first thought that's what `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi` and `AddInMemoryTokenCaches` were doing below and somehow `DefaultAzureCredential` would leverage that but that is obviously not working.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(this.Configuration,
                                        "AzureAd")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]
                                                       {
                                                           "user.read"
                                                       })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    
    ...
```

AppSettings.json:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "TenantId": "c9db0b8f-****-****-****-************",
    "ClientId": "318b64c3-****-****-****-************",
    "ClientSecret": "vh27Q*********************",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "AzureKeyVaultSettings": {
    "KeyVaultBaseUrl": "https://myspecialvault.vault.azure.net/"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The errors I'm getting in my azure app service are:

```
2022-03-19 11:32:49.842 +00:00 [Critical] AzureKeyVaultDashboard.Web.Controllers.HomeController: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.- SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at D:\DWASFiles\Sites\myazkvdashboard\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json- Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot- Azure CLI not installed- PowerShell is not installed.---> System.AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were encountered while attempting to authenticate. (EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot) (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.) (SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.) (Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at D:\DWASFiles\Sites\myazkvdashboard\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json) (Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot) (Azure CLI not installed) (PowerShell is not installed.)---> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshootat Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)at Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)--- End of inner exception stack trace ------> (Inner Exception #1) Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.---> System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (100.100.100.100:80)) (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (100.100.100.100:80)) (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (100.100.100.100:80)) (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (100.100.100.100:80))
```

All of this functionality appears to work fine when testing locally.

I'm using

- .net 6
- Azure.Identity - 1.5
- Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets - 4.2

Comment: In your app registration (used for users to authenticate to your app) you have delegated permission  to key vault (in API permissions)?

Comment: @Thomas In my App Registration under "Api permissions" I have an entry for Azure Key Vault where the "Type" of permission is configured as "Delegated" and under this permission it's also listed as "user_impersonation".

Comment: THat's good start. I think you need to add this scope in the `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi` call. Not sure if just `https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation` would work but worse gie it a try.

Comment: @Thomas I added `https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation` but I'm still having the same issues.  It works locally but when I deploy it as an Azure App Service I get the same errors as mentioned above about it not finding any tokens with the `DefaultAzureCredential`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though the `DefaultAzureCredential` doesn't really work in my case.  I had to inject an `ITokenAcquisition` object into my constructor and use a `ChainedCredential` like this instead of just using `DefaultAzureCredential`:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(this.azureKeyVaultSettings.Value.KeyVaultBaseUrl),
                              new ChainedTokenCredential(new TokenAcquisitionTokenCredential(this.tokenAcquisition),
                                                               new DefaultAzureCredential());

var secrets = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();
```

I also had to add the `https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation` to the `.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()` call.  See below Startup.cs correction from my original post:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(this.Configuration,
                                    "AzureAd")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]
                                                   {
                                                       "https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation",
                                                       "user.read"
                                                   })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

The `.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()` is what allows the `ITokenAcquisition` to be injected in controllers. See here for more detail:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#startupcs

Comment: Good to see that you manage to get it working :-0

Answer (score 0):

On deployment of keyvault and app service, you can set the access policy at keyvault for app service using principal ID of app service. In this way, the web app hosted under app service will get the access to keyvault.
You can use azure ad authentication to authenticate the user logging in and then provide the key vault detail on your web application.

Please check and comment whether it works for you.

Comment: If you are talking about using a "System" or "User" assigned [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) I don't want to do that.  I want to use the Azure Active Directory user's rights/roles.  That is how our organization is currently managing access to Azure KeyVault secrets.  If I created a managed identity it would have different access levels than the Azure Active Directory user (ex. user@microsoft.com).